# Exercise on Multivariable Calculus using mean value theorem

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Let $\;f \in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R^n; \mathbb R)\;$ a nonnegative
>   function that vanishes on a finite set $\;A \subset \mathbb R^n\;$.
>   Assume the matrix $\; \frac{{\partial}^2 f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial
>  x_j}\;$ is positive definite for every $\;a \in A\;$.
>
> I want to show that $\;f_x(x)(x-a)\;$ is positive, where
>   $\;f_x\;=\;{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \dots \;,\frac{\partial
>  f}{\partial x_n})}^Τ \;$

**My approach:**

Since $\;a\;$ is stationary point for $\;f\;$ I wrote:

$\;f_x(x)(x-a)=\;(f_x(x)-f_x(a))(x-a)=\;f_{xx}(y)(x-a)^2\;$ for $\;y \in (x,a)\;$. If I could somehow show that $\;f_{xx}(y)\;$ is positive, the exercise would be done.

At this point I've been stuck, I can't come up with any good idea.
Any help would be valuable! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: But $f_{xx}$ is positive definite by hypothesis..

Comment: @RafaBudría $\;f_{xx}\;$ is positive definite for every $\;a \in A\;$.